# jade static anchor link with dynamic link data from server side

Tags: pug

Does jade is able to do following, combine static html list with dynamic anchor list from server side.

```
ul
        li
            a(href='/') Home
if data.links
    each link, i in data.links
        li
            a(href='' + link.url)= link.title
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You're just using the wrong indentation and format:

```
ul
    li
        a(href="/") Home
    if data.links
        each link, i in data.links
            li
                a(href=link.url) #{link.title}
```